# WCF IErrorHandler to return FaultException to SOAP and WebHttpException to POX and Json endpoints

Tags: wcf, rest, soap

I have a set of SOAP webservices that are wrapping exceptions using IErrorHandler, specifically:

```
public sealed class ErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{
    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
        // don't wrap existing fault exceptions
        if ((error is FaultException)) return;

        // our basic service fault
        var businessFault = new BusinessFault { FaultMessage = error.Message, FaultReference = "Internal" };

        // Resource based faultReason
        var faultReason = new FaultReason(Properties.Resources.BusinessFaultReason);
        var faultcode = FaultCodeFactory.CreateVersionAwareSenderFaultCode(InternalFaultCodes.BusinessFailure.ToString(), Service.Namespace);

        var faultException = new FaultException<BusinessFault>(
            businessFault,
            faultReason,
            faultcode);

        // Create message fault
        var messageFault = faultException.CreateMessageFault();

        // Create message using Message Factory method
        fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, messageFault, faultException.Action);
    }
}
```

I have now added extra endpoints for Json and Pox which work fine, unless an exception occurs. In the case of the Json endpoint the FaultException is returned as XML.

I am aware from other SO posts that in the case of REST I would be better throwing a WebHttpException:

```
throw new WebFaultException<BusinessFault>(detail, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
```

Or overriding the response message properties in ProvideFault, thus:

```
var wbf = new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Json);
fault.Properties.Add(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name, wbf);

var rmp = new HttpResponseMessageProperty
{
    StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
    StatusDescription = "See fault object for more information."
};
fault.Properties.Add(HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name, rmp);
```

However, MSDN has some interesting remarks about [WebHttpException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webfaultexception.aspx) namely:

> When using a WCF REST endpoint (WebHttpBinding and WebHttpBehavior or
>   WebScriptEnablingBehavior) the HTTP status code on the response is set
>   accordingly. However, WebFaultException can be used with non-REST
>   endpoints and behaves like a regular FaultException.
>
> When using a WCF REST endpoint, the response format of the serialized
>   fault is determined in the same way as a non-fault response. For more
>   information about WCF REST formatting, see WCF REST Formatting.

It would suggest therefore that I need to convert my current ProvideFault method to provide a new WebHttpException (wrapping any existing Exceptions or FaultExceptions) and then SOAP would still work as well.

Would anyone like to take a stab at what that would look like (.Net4.0 btw)? I want one error handler to rule them all!

Comment: i don't understand your question. Do you want to have a unique implementation of IErrorHandler for JSON/POX/SOAP endpoint ?

Comment: @Cybermaxs correct. WCF lets you expose multiple endpoints to different types of client. This all works well, until you need to raise faults. If I raise (generically) a SOAP fault, then the HTTP clients will be none the wiser. If I raise a HTTP fault, then the SOAP clients are then left in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that using `webHttpBinding` was a way to get the "all-in-one" functionality of JSON/POX/SOAP as opposed to using separate bindings for each (i.e. `wsHttpBinding`, `basicHttpBinding` etc.). So wouldn't you be able to just throw the `WebHttpException` and then have that give you all the error details you needed regardless of the technology?

Answer (score 0):

In a REST application I'm working on, I created a new class derived from `WebFaultException<T>` that attaches some additional data to caught service exceptions. Calling the `CreatingMessageFault()` method on the instance of the derived class let me return my selected exception data from the `ProvideFault()` method of the error handler as the SOAP fault, letting WCF determine the correct message format.

I am using `webHttpBinding` to bind all but some third-party services.

**Edit: Added code example**

```
public class ErrorHandler : IErrorHandler, IServiceBehavior
{       
    public virtual void ProvideFault( Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault )
    {
        // Include next level of detail in message, if any.
        MyFaultException myFaultException =
            ((error is MyFaultException) &&
                ((MyFaultException)error).Detail != null)
            ? new MyFaultException(error.Message + " - " +
                    ((MyFaultException)error).Detail.Message, error)
            : new MyFaultException( error.Message, error );
        MessageFault messageFault = myFaultException.CreateMessageFault();
        fault = Message.CreateMessage( version, messageFault, myFaultException.Action );
    }
}
```

and

```
/// <summary>
/// Class used to return exception data from my WCF services.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// This class is used by a web service to pass exception data back and a
/// data object to the client. This class inherits WebFaultException, which
/// is handled specially by the WCF WebServiceHost2 service class and
/// generates a WebException on the client.
/// </remarks>
public class MyFaultException : WebFaultException<BusinessFault>
{
public class MyFaultException : WebFaultException<BusinessFault>
{
    public MyFaultException(string message)
        : this(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, message) { }

    public MyFaultException(HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message)
        : base(new BusinessFault(message), statusCode) { }
}
```

then in your service, you can throw the exception to pass fault data to your client:

```
        try
        {
            // Successful operation proceeds normally.
        }
        catch (ApplicationException e)
        {
            // Failure generates MyFaultException.
            throw new MyFaultException("Operation failed with " + e.Message);
        }
```

Comment: If you would like to add a code example I would be able to try out what you have described.

Comment: I'll try and find some time to give this a try. I'll happily sort you out with the credit for the answer then. It might take a while though since I haven't worked on this project for a while!