# Set defaultBodyStyle attribute for WebHttpBehavior via C# code

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm having a WCF-Service and i want access this service by a C# client. Unfortunately my C# client is written in .Net 3.5 and i have no chanche to change to a higher .Net version. My problem now is, that i have to configure an endpointbehaviour like

```
<behaviors>
   <endpointBehaviors>
       <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp defaultBodyStyle="Wrapped"/>
       </behavior>
   </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

But on .Net 3.5 the defaultBodyStyle attribute does not exists. I've found the similar problem here:

[Consume Json WCF service with .Net 3.5 client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095621/consume-json-wcf-service-with-net-3-5-client)

The solution should be to set value in code by using the WebHttpBehavior class.
But i do not understand how to code it. First problem is, that in my project this class does not exists (in the System.ServiceModel.Description namespace).

Assume i've created my WCF client like:

```
myServiceReference.ImyServiceClient client = new myServiceReference.ImyServiceClient("myEndpoint);
```

How can i set the value for the defaultBodyStyle of the WebHttp behaviour by using the WebHttpBehavior class??

Thanks in advance ....

Comment: The problem, that i the class is not found in my project is solved (by reference the System.ServiceModel.Web.dll to the project). But i still don't know how to implement it.